# remove spaces in between <xsl:text> using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

input xml:

```
<keywords>

  <ce:keyword>

    <ce:text>

      spacetime

    </ce:text>

  </ce:keyword>

  <ce:keyword>

    <ce:text>

      cauchy surface

    </ce:text>

  </ce:keyword>

</keyword>
```

xsl so far i am using is,

```
<xsl:copy-of select="replace(ce:keywords/ce:keyword,'\s*','')"/>
```

i used this xsl:copy-of and replace function .but no changes in my output xml.

i want to remove spaces or empty newline in between the .

can anyone help me to this?

my expexted output xml is,

```
<keywords>

  <ce:keyword>

    <ce:text>spacetime</ce:text>

  </ce:keyword>

  <ce:keyword>

    <ce:text>cauchy surface</ce:text>

  </ce:keyword>

</keywords>
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<xsl:template match="ce:text">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

`normalize-space` function takes care of the extraneous spaces.